# TextView text reuses and replace on scrolling swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, tableview, xib

I have a dynamic form having multiple components ( button, textfield, textview). I have used a xib file for the form. I have solved the issue for button and textfield but couldnt solve the issue for table View.[image]

Comment: Its because TableView reuses the cell, and because your textView is part of the cell, it seems like text view text is reused, what you can do is use `prepareForReuse` method of tableView cell and set your `textView.text = nil` to avoid the issue, if you are not saving the text in your data model adding above code will lead you to loose the user's text completely, hence use textView delegate to find when user is done with typing and save what user entered into a data model and finally, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` repopulate the textView's text property from your data model before returning cell

Comment: " I have solved the issue for button and textfield but couldnt solve the issue for table View." How did you do that? I see that I commented your previous question about that but there wasn't any response from you. Also, it's the same logic. Cells are reused, so manage that: "Reset their state if needed".

Comment: you need to use a model to fill your data so the model is an array of the struct which can contains many things like text,color,etc . then you will use that array to fill the textfields, textviews and ... , so in your table view cell for row function it will be some thing like this 
cell.textView.text = model[indexPath.row].textViewText 
 and your model will be some thing like this 

struct TableViewModel {
var textViewText = String()
var textFieldText = String()
}

and in your view controller will be some thing like this 
var model :  [TableViewModel] = []